# How to make an UIView into circle shape in swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift

The width(40) and height(40) of the UIView are equal.

I have tried these but they didn't work for me:

```
countView?.clipsToBounds = true
self.countView?.layer.cornerRadius = min((countView?.frame.size.width)!, (countView?.frame.size.height)!)/2
```

and also

```
self.countView.layer.cornerRadius = (countView.frame.size.width)/2
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you get now?

Comment: UIView have layer indeed is it shapeable tho, depends on whats inside the bounds of that View, and there constraints and frames

Comment: First print `countView.frame.size.width` and see what is the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mask layer like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.countView.bounds).cgPath;
    self.countView.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

**Example Output**

Here the output of a UIView with width/height = 128/128:

[image: example output]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Stephan answer.

With less code:

```
self.countView.layer.cornerRadius = self.countView.bounds.height / 2
```

Result:

[image: img]